# Intermittent Deadlock on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 With TABLOCK, XLOCK Commands

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I'm getting intermittent deadlocks with the following stored procedure. It is run once per minute.  It's been in production for 1+ years and we don't usually get this error but it crops up sometimes... it's throwing exceptions 3 to 5 time a day in one of our environments... it's the same environment as other instances that are not throwing the error. The stored procedure was made so it can only be running once at a time, but maybe the way we are doing it is not proper?

Here is the error:

> *System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 60) was
>   deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen
>   as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.*

Here is the stored procedure:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[requestUpdate]
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime,
            @EndDate datetime,
            @Throttle bit,
            @Expired bit

    SELECT @Throttle = 0
    SELECT @Expired = 0

    SELECT TOP 1 @StartDate = uq.StartDate, @EndDate = uq.EndDate
      FROM UpdateQueue uq WITH(TABLOCK,XLOCK)
     ORDER BY ID DESC

    -- PREVENT ANOTHER REQUEST IF THIS SP HAS BEEN
    -- CALLED IN THE LAST FORTY SECONDS.
    IF DATEADD(SECOND,-40,GETDATE()) < @StartDate
    BEGIN
      SELECT @Throttle = 1
    END

    -- CREATE ANOTHER REQUEST IF THE CURRENT ONE
    -- HAS NOT COMPLETED IN THE LAST FIVE MINUTES.
    IF @StartDate <= DATEADD(MINUTE,-5,GETDATE())
    BEGIN
      SELECT @Expired = 1
    END

    -- HAS THE CURRENT REQUEST EXPIRED?
    IF @EndDate IS NULL AND @Expired = 1
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO UpdateQueue (RequestID, StartDate) OUTPUT 'EXPIRED' AS Result, INSERTED.RequestID AS RequestID
      VALUES (NEWID(), GETDATE())
    END

    -- HAS THE CURRENT REQUEST COMPLETED AND YOU ARE NOT THROTTLING
    -- OR HAVE THERE NOT BEEN ANY REQUESTS YET?
    ELSE IF (@EndDate IS NOT NULL AND @Throttle = 0) OR @StartDate IS NULL
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO UpdateQueue (RequestID, StartDate) OUTPUT 'STARTED' AS Result, INSERTED.RequestID AS RequestID
      VALUES (NEWID(), GETDATE())
    END

    -- Running
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SELECT 'RUNNING' AS Result, NULL AS RequestID
    END

COMMIT
```

Comment: you should use [app locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) to achieve sp execution exclusion, not table X locks. As about the deadlock: capture and post the deadlock graph (the XML, not the picture!), see [Save Deadlock Graphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a matter of a particular lock being held for longer than your connection is willing to wait.  Without something to kill off a long-running transaction, here, you're going to run into this because when the connection times out SQL Server forces the waiting to end & kills off the incoming lock as the deadlock victim.

Long story short: some process (not the one detailed here) is locking the table, causing a deadlock.

Examine what else is taking place when you're experiencing the deadlock - is there a backup running, or something else which locks this table?